# DFS-style Replication for Samba?

Tags: replication, glusterfs, dfs-r, samba4

I've been snooping around here for a while, and it looks as if glusterfs might be the answer to my question. However, I am fairly new to this, so a sanity check would be much appreciated!

My setup is two Samba boxes at two geographically disparate locations. Both will serve as a file server for shares accessed at both locations. What I had in mind is some kind of real-time file mirroring to/from location 1 and location 2, so both machines will have an up-to-date set of user files all the time. Of course, some kind of write lock would be nice as well. Upstream at both locations is a reliable 10Mb/s.

From what I gather, in a Windows environment, DFS-R probably is what I am looking for. What's a sensible alternative in the Linux world?

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Mike